# What is the best data structure to store chunks of file in python

Tags: python

I want to store chunks of file in a list so that later on a can perform some operations with the map function on each chunks. Intuitively I am tempted to to something like below (but it doesn't work):

```
fi = open(fileName, "rb")
data = fi.read()
fi.close()

max = len(data)
block = 1024

tmp = []
for i in range(0, max, block):
    tmp.append(data[i:i+block])
```

Comment: Avoid using `max` as a variable name - this shadows the built-in function `max()`.

Comment: "it doesn't work". Can you clarify *what* doesn't work? Does it raise an error? Does it give an unexpected result (in this case show what would be the expected result *and* what is the result you get).

Comment: In most cases creating a list of chunks may be just useless memory use, as you can read the file chunk by chunk. And in any case, you will have to handle the last (incomplete) chunk differently. But as Bakurlu points out in his answer, the file.read() function takes the chunk size as a parameter. If there are fewer octets to read, read() returns as many as it can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to read the file by chunks in the first place:

```
block = 1024
with open(fileName, 'rb') as f:
    tmp = [chunk for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(block), b'')]
```

See the documentation for [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter).